# How can I monitor battery state on a laptop running FreeBSD 8?

Tags: power-management, freebsd

Is there any console tool that can be used to view battery status on a laptop (Dell Vostro A860) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `apm` command has existed for a while now -- try the `sysutils/hwstat` port (pulls battery info from ACPI).

There are plenty of X11/graphical battery meters in ports but that's the only one I'm aware of that works on the console.

Comment: It was certainly there in 7 and the man pages say it's still there in 8.

Comment: Yes, it's still there in my 8-STABLE VM (which was installed clean from 8.0-RELEASE).

Answer (score 3):

You want [`apm -b`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=apm&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.0-RELEASE&format=html).

Answer (score 2):

Try `acpiconf -i 0` or `acpiconf -i 0 | grep Remaining`.

Consider creating an alias such as `battery` to make it easier to find the information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using such script in my conky config

```
sysctl -n hw.acpi.battery.life
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
acpiconf -i 0 ; man acpiconf
```